# Run bicep from devops build pipeline. ERROR: unrecognized arguments: ENDPOINT_DATA

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

From a devops build pipeline, I'd like to run a bicep file for a deployment into a resource group.

My devops service connection is names '365response-tfssc-dev', as seen below:

[image]

My yaml job is as follows:

```
- job: deployAzure
        displayName: deploy bicep to Azure
        pool:
          vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"
        dependsOn: [waitForValidation]

        steps:
          - task: AzureCLI@2
            displayName: Deploy Bicep To Azure
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: "365response-tfssc-dev"
              scriptType: "bash"
              scriptLocation: "inlineScript"
              inlineScript: |
                az deployment group create --resource-group rg-365Response-$(env)-001 \
                  --template-file '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\bicep\365Response.main.bicep' \
                  --parameters '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\bicep\365Response.parameters.$(env).json' \
```

If I run this from the terminal window of vs code then it works ok.

When this job runs it gives the following message:

> /usr/bin/az account set --subscription 'correct subscription id is
> listed here' /usr/bin/bash
> /home/vsts/work/_temp/azureclitaskscript1654444101122.sh ERROR:
> unrecognized arguments:
> ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_SERVICEMANAGEMENTURL=https://m...
> this line is very very long

The very long line is as follows:

```
ERROR: unrecognized arguments: ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_SERVICEMANAGEMENTURL=https://management.core.windows.net/ ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_ENVIRONMENT=AzureCloud ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_ARMMANAGEMENTPORTALURL=https://portal.azure.com/ ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_MANAGEMENTPORTALURL=https://manage.windowsazure.com/ ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_GALLERYURL=https://gallery.azure.com/ ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_SUBSCRIPTIONID=subIdHere ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8={"environment":"AzureCloud","scopeLevel":"Subscription","subscriptionId":"subIdHere","subscriptionName":"dev-001","creationMode":"Manual","environmentUrl":"https://management.azure.com/","galleryUrl":"https://gallery.azure.com/","serviceManagementUrl":"https://management.core.windows.net/","resourceManagerUrl":"https://management.azure.com/","activeDirectoryAuthority":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/","environmentAuthorityUrl":"https://login.windows.net/","graphUrl":"https://graph.windows.net/","managementPortalUrl":"https://manage.windowsazure.com/","armManagementPortalUrl":"https://portal.azure.com/","activeDirectoryServiceEndpointResourceId":"https://management.core.windows.net/","sqlDatabaseDnsSuffix":".database.windows.net","AzureKeyVaultDnsSuffix":"vault.azure.net","AzureKeyVaultServiceEndpointResourceId":"https://vault.azure.net","StorageEndpointSuffix":"core.windows.net","EnableAdfsAuthentication":"false"} ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_SQLDATABASEDNSSUFFIX=.database.windows.net ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_ENVIRONMENTAUTHORITYURL=https://login.windows.net/ ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_CREATIONMODE=Manual ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_AZUREKEYVAULTSERVICEENDPOINTRESOURCEID=https://vault.azure.net ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_SUBSCRIPTIONNAME=dev-001 ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_AZUREKEYVAULTDNSSUFFIX=vault.azure.net ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_SCOPELEVEL=Subscription agent.jobstatus=Succeeded ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_ACTIVEDIRECTORYSERVICEENDPOINTRESOURCEID=https://management.core.windows.net/ ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_GRAPHURL=https://graph.windows.net/ ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_ENVIRONMENTURL=https://management.azure.com/ ENDPOINT_URL_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8=https://management.azure.com/ ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_ACTIVEDIRECTORYAUTHORITY=https://login.microsoftonline.com/ ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_ENABLEADFSAUTHENTICATION=false ENDPOINT_DATA_7940768d-1de7-44d9-92bf-05d293639bc8_RESOURCEMANAGERURL=https://management.azure.com/ SELENIUM_JAR_PATH=/usr/share/java/selenium-server.jar COMMON_TESTRESULTSDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/work/1/TestResults GOROOT_1_17_X64=/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.17.10/x64 CONDA=/usr/share/miniconda SYSTEM_JOBNAME=__default AGENT_RETAINDEFAULTENCODING=false JAVA_HOME_11_X64=/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-11-jdk-amd64 SYSTEM_PIPELINESTARTTIME=2022-06-05 15:48:16+00:00 AZURE_CONFIG_DIR=/home/vsts/work/_temp/.azclitask SYSTEM_TASKINSTANCENAME=AzureCLI AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/agents/2.204.0 AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/work/_temp BUILD_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL=aza.'my email here' VSTS_PROCESS_LOOKUP_ID=vsts_8ec9ddb3-be14-4d39-96fe-b09bdd94b311 SYSTEM_COLLECTIONURI=https://dev.azure.com/idsservicesbeta/ BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME=Scaffolding (1) ENDPOINT_URL_SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION=https://dev.azure.com/idsservicesbeta/ JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-11-jdk-amd64 GRADLE_HOME=/usr/share/gradle-7.4.2 SYSTEM_STAGENAME=deployBicep SYSTEM_JOBPARALLELISMTAG=Private AGENT_OS=Linux BUILD_BUILDURI=vstfs:///Build/Build/1755 AGENT_JOBNAME=deploy bicep to Azure XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/home/vsts/.config DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE=1 BUILD_REPOSITORY_URI=https://idsservicesbeta@dev.azure.com/idsservicesbeta/365-Response/_git/Scaffolding ANT_HOME=/usr/share/ant RESOURCES_TRIGGERINGALIAS= JAVA_HOME_8_X64=/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-8-jdk-amd64 BUILD_DEFINITIONVERSION=1 HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew RUNNER_TOOLSDIRECTORY=/opt/hostedtoolcache SYSTEM_SERVERTYPE=Hosted AGENT_USEWORKSPACEID=true BUILD_REQUESTEDFORID=08c91bb3-5fb2-6b27-a830-47c6829ed7f8 SYSTEM_JOBIDENTIFIER=deployBicep.deployAzure.__default SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/work/1/a AGENT_VERSION=2.204.0 HOMEBREW_CLEANUP_PERIODIC_FULL_DAYS=3650 BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONAUTHOR=BizTalkers SYSTEM_JOBDISPLAYNAME=deploy bicep to Azure BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME=Scaffolding BOOTSTRAP_HASKELL_NONINTERACTIVE=1 PWD=/home/vsts/work/1/s PIPX_BIN_DIR=/opt/pipx_bin BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/work/1/a AGENT_ACCEPTTEEEULA=True BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME=main AGENT_UPLOADTIMELINEATTACHMENTSTOBLOB=true TASK_DISPLAYNAME=Deploy Bicep To Azure BUILD_CONTAINERID=27996509 ANDROID_NDK_LATEST_HOME=/usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk/23.2.8568313 RESOURCES_TRIGGERINGCATEGORY= POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL=Azure-DevOps-ubuntu20 SYSTEM_STAGEDISPLAYNAME=deployBicep SYSTEM_PLANID=6892c8d0-c78e-4c67-b035-05b3489e50dc SYSTEM_POSTLINESSPEED=500 BUILD_BUILDNUMBER=Deploy Bicep files 1755 DOTNET_MULTILEVEL_LOOKUP=0 BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH=/home/vsts/work/1/s VSTS_AGENT_PERFLOG=/home/vsts/perflog HOME=/home/vsts LANG=C.UTF-8 BUILD_REPOSITORY_PROVIDER=TfsGit STATS_KEEPALIVE=false SYSTEM_TIMELINEID=6892c8d0-c78e-4c67-b035-05b3489e50dc SYSTEM_PHASEDISPLAYNAME=deploy bicep to Azure SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI=https://dev.azure.com/idsservicesbeta/ BUILD_STAGINGDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/work/1/a SYSTEM_HOSTTYPE=build AGENT_WORKFOLDER=/home/vsts/work SYSTEM_STAGEID=bc4f992b-d3a8-5fa4-4306-364494a1b562 SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID=45 INVOCATION_ID=ddfbd830e49e4577879f4d283f4ac321 INPUT_SCRIPTARGUMENTS= AGENT_DISABLELOGPLUGIN_TESTFILEPUBLISHERPLUGIN=true TF_BUILD=True JAVA_HOME_17_X64=/usr/lib/jvm/temurin-17-jdk-amd64 AGENT_TASKRESTRICTIONSENFORCEMENTMODE=Enabled AGENT_ROOTDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/work SYSTEM_JOBATTEMPT=1 ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk-bundle SYSTEM_DEFINITIONNAME=Scaffolding (1) HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/work/1/b NVM_DIR=/home/vsts/.nvm SGX_AESM_ADDR=1 SYSTEM_PHASEATTEMPT=1 SYSTEM_ENABLEACCESSTOKEN=SecretVariable SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI=https://dev.azure.com/idsservicesbeta/ SYSTEM_TASKDISPLAYNAME=Deploy Bicep To Azure BUILD_BUILDID=1755 TEMPLATEFILE=bicep/365Response.main.json BUILD_REPOSITORY_ID=92e4e7ea-8e17-425b-ad1c-899f9922bc0f AGENT_NAME=Hosted Agent ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/lib/android/sdk SYSTEM_JOBPOSITIONINPHASE=1 AGENT_MACHINENAME=fv-az414-868 ACCEPT_EULA=Y SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_ISFORK=False SYSTEM_JOBTIMEOUT=60 SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID=4009b106-170a-496d-9af8-9ec836b38dc3 SYSTEM_COLLECTIONID=b3e27278-2d93-48a2-af86-fa3370179011 USER=vsts SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT=365-Response HOMEBREW_CELLAR=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar BUILD_SOURCEVERSION=715f5872b0f65eade29314d0f30bf57a3f191896 PIPX_HOME=/opt/pipx AGENT_DISABLELOGPLUGIN_TESTRESULTLOGPLUGIN=true SYSTEM_PHASEID=f1ebf77f-30ac-526d-968c-fab23fa199f8 GECKOWEBDRIVER=/usr/local/share/gecko_driver BUILD_REASON=Manual SYSTEM_STAGEATTEMPT=1 CHROMEWEBDRIVER=/usr/local/share/chrome_driver SHLVL=0 SYSTEM=build ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/usr/local/lib/android/sdk VCPKG_INSTALLATION_ROOT=/usr/local/share/vcpkg HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew ImageVersion=20220529.1 BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH=refs/heads/main AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT=VSTS_b3e27278-2d93-48a2-af86-fa3370179011_build_45_0 DOTNET_NOLOGO=1 BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/work/1/s MSDEPLOY_HTTP_USER_AGENT=VSTS_b3e27278-2d93-48a2-af86-fa3370179011_build_45_0 TASK_SKIPTRANSLATORFORCHECKOUT=False SYSTEM_CULTURE=en-US SYSTEM_WORKFOLDER=/home/vsts/work STATS_PFS=true GRAALVM_11_ROOT=/usr/local/graalvm/graalvm-ce-java11-22.1.0 AGENT_READONLYVARIABLES=true AGENT_ID=8 BUILD_QUEUEDBYID=08c91bb3-5fb2-6b27-a830-47c6829ed7f8 AZURE_EXTENSION_DIR=/opt/az/azcliextensions AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/work/1 BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR=Rob Bowman ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/usr/local/lib/android/sdk/ndk-bundle CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome AGENT_UPLOADBUILDARTIFACTSTOBLOB=true SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY=/home/vsts/work/1/s GOROOT_1_18_X64=/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.18.2/x64 JOURNAL_STREAM=8:23147 AGENT_OSARCHITECTURE=X64 LEIN_HOME=/usr/local/lib/lein LEIN_JAR=/usr/local/lib/lein/self-installs/leiningen-2.9.8-standalone.jar SYSTEM_ISSCHEDULED=False BUILD_REPOSITORY_GIT_SUBMODULECHECKOUT=False PATH=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/vsts/.local/bin:/opt/pipx_bin:/home/vsts/.cargo/bin:/home/vsts/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/.ghcup/bin:/home/vsts/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin SYSTEM_JOBID=d562b731-90ac-599c-aa5d-b4e5e0c32cf4 BUILD_QUEUEDBY=Rob Bowman SWIFT_PATH=/usr/share/swift/usr/bin PIPELINE_WORKSPACE=/home/vsts/work/1 ImageOS=ubuntu20 BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE=ubuntu-latest SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI=https://dev.azure.com/idsservicesbeta/ AGENT_LOGTOBLOBSTORAGESERVICE=true LOCATION=uksouth SYSTEM_TASKINSTANCEID=44b963b8-127f-5c06-baab-44a1330fee42 AGENT_JOBSTATUS=Succeeded DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY=/opt/hostedtoolcache SYSTEM_PHASENAME=deployAzure OLDPWD=/home/vsts/work/1/s SYSTEM_TOTALJOBSINPHASE=1 GOROOT_1_16_X64=/opt/hostedtoolcache/go/1.16.15/x64 _=/usr/bin/env-001
```

Anyone see where I've gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

0. Please check if your service connection's Azure AD service principal has access to the Azure subscription you are trying to deploy to. Your error message doesn't really look like that, but the error message is not fully shown in your question. (That "very long" error message can be very important. ;) )
1. Most likely you should debug the `az deployment group create ...` script locally with the variable values replaced for yourself manually, and see if you can reproduce the error. That would mean that Azure Pipelines has nothing to do with this, you should just make your deployment instruction work and all will be good.
2. If #1 is not applicable for you (e.g. your deployment instruction is working totally fine locally but it is still failing in the pipeline), my recommendation is to look into Azure CLI version on the pipelines agent vs. the one you need and maybe add az Azure CLI upgrade/downgrade task to suit your needs.

For example, we have used these 2 steps to update AzureCLI when the MS hosted agent version contained a bug.

```
- script: sudo apt-get update

- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.armServiceConnection }}
    scriptType: 'bash'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |-
      az --version
      curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash
      az --version
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I can confirm that if I run the az deployment command from a terminal window in vscode then it works. I have added the task that you gave me to indicate the latest version of the Azure cli and it confirmed that the latest version was already installed. I have now also added the full text from the very long error message

Answer (score 0):

Problem was using ubuntu image - should have been windows-2022